# how to use wow.js or any other library in react

Tags: reactjs, wow.js

I need help please I started using react in my first project and I'm facing a problem with installing wow js I searched a lot on the internet but all I found was old methods that don't work now someone help, please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install the dependency first

```
npm install wowjs
```

then import in the required component

```
import WOW from 'wowjs';
```

and in a method `componentDidMount` (for class components) or a hook `useEffect` (for functional) create an instance and initiate

```
componentDidMount() {
  new WOW.WOW({
    live: false
  }).init();
}

useEffect(() => {
  new WOW.WOW({
    live: false
  }).init();
}, [])
```